# Failing to delete GCP project due to non-existent DialogFlow agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to delete a GCP project.

Now, it used to have a Google Assistant integration (~ 3 years ago) but now I don't need it anymore and I want to delete it.

When I try to delete the project -> it tells me it can't because it's liked to a Dataflow agent. It provides me with a link but when I follow it, there are no agents listed there. I browsed all available regions, but no agents are listed.

I went to Actions from GCP console, but I can't delete the Actions project either (same reason). When I go to my defined action, I am prompted to migrate to Actions Builder (but I get a generic error trying to do that). In any case, if I try to edit my action in Dataflow, it takes me to the same homepage which prompts me to create an agent - as it doesn't list any.

So I'm stumped - I can't delete my project because of an existing Dataflow agent but Dataflow doesn't list any agents in any region.

Can anyone with Dataflow/GCP experience provide any insight into anything I may try ? Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is to deactivate the Dialogflow API from the GCP console, please follow the steps: 1.- Open  [APIs & Services dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)  2.- Click on Dialogflow API 3.- Click on Disable API. After disabling the Dialogflow API, you should be able to delete your project. You can also follow this [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/troubleshooting?agent=any&category=project#project-lien). Let me know if this solved your issue or not.

Comment: @kiranmathew strangely enough, this doesn't work either. So I disabled the Dialogflow API and it told me that resources created via Dialogflow may be deleted - however 2h later, with the API disabled, still can't delete my project due to the exact same error as before.

Comment: I think that even though you deleted the agent, the lien used by the  agent is not deleted. Run this CLI command  `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list` to list liens and then run the `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete LIEN_NAME ` command then you can try again to delete the project. For more information, you can refer to the [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/troubleshooting?agent=any&category=project#project-lien). Let me know if this solved your issue or not.

Comment: @kiranmathew indeed, this has solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Andrei Dascalu  If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are mainly two possible situations for the issue `Failing to delete GCP project due to non-existent DialogFlow agent`:

1. The agent has been deleted, but the lien was not deleted.
2. The agent was not deleted.

You can follow the steps below to solve the issue:

1. Delete the agents associated with the project and try again to delete the project. If this does not solve the issue then follow `step2`.
2. Even though you deleted the agent, the lien used by the  agent is not deleted. Run this CLI command  `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list` to list liens and then run the `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete LIEN_NAME`  command then you can try again to delete the project. For more information, you can refer to the [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/troubleshooting?agent=any&category=project#project-lien). If this does not solve the issue then follow `step3`.
3. Deactivate the Dialogflow API from the GCP console: Open  [APIs & Services dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)  then click on Dialogflow API then click on Disable API. After disabling the Dialogflow API, try again to delete the project.

Comment: you are an angel!